# Card title disappear despite z-index?

Tags: html, css, web-deployment

I'm trying to make a card with a title and description but when I set a background image on that image, my card title disappeared but not my description. It happens even if I do the same code for both of them.

I know I don't have to write here animation codes too but I really don't have any idea why this is happening.

Image:

[image]

`z-index` doesn't work I guess.

```css
.index {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: white;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 30px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.index_img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}

.index_html {
  background-image: url(web_image_html.jpeg);
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  z-index: -1;
}

.index a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.index_title {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.index_description {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  font-family: 'Inter', sans-serif;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.index_title,
.index_description {
  background-color: rgba(82, 81, 81, 0.56);
  height: 80px;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  z-index: 1;
}

.index_html:hover {
  animation: index-animate 3s ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes index-animate {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1.3);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="index">
  <a href="">
    <div class="index_img index_html"></div>
    <h2 class="index_title">HTML</h2>
    <p class="index_description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove overflow hidden from the below code

```
.index {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: white;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 30px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  position: relative;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track! But you're fumbling a little with the usage of `display: flex;` and `position: absolute;`. `display: flex;` should be used on the parent to see the result on the child(ren), you're using it directly on the children (`.index_title` and `.index_description`).

For trying to position 2 elements together with `position: absolute;` I'd recommend wrapping them together, so you only have to position 1 element!

```css
.index {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: white;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 30px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;

}

.index_img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
}

.index_html {
    background: url(web_image_html.jpeg) red;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    z-index: -1;
}

.index a {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.index_content {
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: rgba(82, 81, 81, 0.56);
}


.index_title {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #000;
}

.index_description {
    font-family: 'Inter', sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
}

.index_title,
.index_description {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

.index_html:hover {
    animation: index-animate 3s ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes index-animate {

    0% {
        transform: scale(1);
    }

    100% {
        transform: scale(1.3);
    }
    
}
```

```html
  <div class="index">
    <a href="">
        <div class="index_img index_html"></div>
        <div class="index_content">
          <h2 class="index_title">HTML</h2>
          <p class="index_description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
        </div>
    </a>
  </div>
```

Comment: The reason why you weren't seeing the `<h2>` was not because it was behind something, it was positioned under the rest of the card. That's why the `z-index` did nothing..